# Adding IBM Db2 as a datasource

Tags: db2, apache-superset

Has anyone had any luck or found documentation on how to add IBM Db2 as a datasource for their dashboard on Apache Superset? I don't see any information in the Db2 service credentials about the driver or dialect.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the docs for Apache Superset the [connections and hence the connection URI are based on SQLAlchemy](https://superset.apache.org/tutorial.html). According to the [Db2 driver for SQLAlchemy](https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdbsa/tree/master/ibm_db_sa), the Db2 database URI would be like this:

```
db2+ibm_db://user:pass@host[:port]/database
```

`db2+ibm_db` is the dialect and driver, `database` is the database name on that host with the specified port (typically 50000). If you want to connect to a local database, just leave out the host/port combination:

```
db2+ibm_db://user:pass@/database
```

Comment: The first link ("connections and hence [...]") only leads back to this question.